# Building an eShop 'Latest Products'

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, dateadd

I was trying to do a 'Latest Products' page for an eShop project I'm working on. Basically, I want to show a number of products, say 10, from a table in my db that where added in my database in the last 30 days or less.

First I tried to use the GridView function in VB.NET, where it auto-populates the table but can't be limited and then I tried this SQL statement, which isn't working, giving me an error.

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE DateAdded > (SELECT DATEADD(d,-30,(SELCT MAX(DateAdded) FROM Product)) AS "Last 30 Products Added");
ORDER BY DateAdded DESC
```

My database has a table called 'Product' which has various columns:

- ProductID
- CategoryID
- ProductModelNo
- ProductImage
- ProductName
- UnitName
- ProductActive
- DateAdded

Any idea on how I can solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the DATEDIFF function to compare the DateAdded with NOW().

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM Product WHERE DATEDIFF(day, DateAdded, NOW()) <= 30 ORDER BY DateAdded DESC`

Comment: Ahh Ok I'll look into the DateDiff function.. Thanks ! One last question, would it be more practical to use the built in DateDiff class from within vb.net ?

Comment: No, leave that to the SQL database! Also when you only want 10 results, add `LIMIT 10` to the end of the query.

Comment: This supposedly did it ! `SELECT ProductImage, ProductName, ProductModelNo, Description, UnitCost
FROM Product
WHERE ([DateAdded] between DateAdd("m", -30, Date()) and Date())`